# vim: run some code every time a buffer changes

Tags: vim

I want to trap all events that modify the vim buffer, so I can record them and send them to a server. I want to trap character-by-character events while in insert mode, and also be notified when `p` or `dd` etc. commands are executed---any time the document changes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps [ttyrec](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ttyrec) can be of help for you

Comment: Are you looking for a [keylogger](https://github.com/igrigorik/vimgolf/blob/master/lib/vimgolf/keylog.rb)? Or something more than this?

Comment: I want to make multiplayer vim (think Etherpad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend pointed me at the terribly-named [netbeans](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/netbeans.html) module within vim. This looks like what I want.

Answer (score 6):

In Vim 8 this is much easier. Just listen to these to autocmd events:

```
TextChanged
TextChangedI
```

Answer (score 3):

Going through the list of events I have selected the following:

```
|BufFilePre|            before changing the name of the current buffer
|BufFilePost|           after changing the name of the current buffer

|FileChangedShell|      Vim notices that a file changed since editing started
|FileChangedShellPost|  After handling a file changed since editing started

|InsertEnter|           starting Insert mode
|InsertChange|          when typing <Insert> while in Insert or Replace mode
|InsertLeave|           when leaving Insert mode

|QuickFixCmdPre|        before a quickfix command is run
|QuickFixCmdPost|       after a quickfix command is run
```

Although I have not tried, I believe that the `Insert*` events include such commands as `d`elete, `p`aste, `c`hange etc. You should also look for the 'Writing' events in |[autocmd-events](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events)|.

Comment: I'm just curious now if it is possible to remap the default vim commands, the so called 'dd' and 'p' for instance ;)

Comment: It would be possible, but would require a huge effort... and may not play nicely with vimrc. Need to handle all variations, too.. eg. '2dd', 'vjjp', 'd3k', etc. Also, none of the Insert* methods trigger when you enter text in insert mode -- only when you enter or leave insert mode.